# percentage of two numbers and show result in another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that consists of `tr` and `td`s and I want to show the percentage of sold ticket in third `td`. For example:

```
(4*100)/30="13"
```

and show the result in third `td`. How can I do this with jquery?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Avalable</th> <!--available-->
<th>Sold</th> <!--used-->
<th>Result</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tr>
<td>30</td> <!--available-->
<td>4</td> <!--used-->
<td><span class="result"></span></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>20 <br/> 20</td> <!--available-->
<td>6  <br/> 5</td>  <!--used-->
<td><span class="result"></span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please include what you've tried so far and which part you are having difficulty with.

Comment: @freedomn-m I am new on this. i wish i coud try somthing

Comment: @aynaz I'll help you.I'm writing solution for you.

Comment: @aynaz Beeing new to something doesn't mean you should not try to attempt your own solution. Please see [**How do I ask a good question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and using your own code you are having issues with, [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - Also, just in general (not in relation to this question), see what Questions [**Are On-Topic**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and which ones [**Are not On-Topic**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over the `tr` and need to generate the value by splitting the content since single cell can contain multiple values.

```js
// iterate ovet the tr inside the tbody
$('table tbody tr').each(function() {
  // cache the reference of this
  var $this = this,
    // get contents inside  second cell and split by non digit chars
    td2Value = $('td:nth-child(2)', $this) // get the second cell
    .html() // get html content
    .trim() // remove leading and trainilng space
    .split(/\D+/); // split by non-digit 
  // get span to show result
  $('span.result', $this).html(
    // get first cell and split content based on non digit and iterate
    $('td:nth-child(1)', $this) // get the first cell
    .html() // get html content
    .trim() // remove leading and trainilng space
    .split(/\D+/) // split by non-digit
    .map(function(v, i) {
      // calculate the percentage, if NaN then return 0
      // and then round the value to remove decimal part
      return Math.round((td2Value[i] * 100 / v) || 0);
      // in case you need 2 decimal part then use toFixed
      // return ((td2Value[i] * 100 / v) || 0).toFixed(2); 
    })
    // join the result with br tag to show in multi line
    .join('<br>'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Avalable</th>
      <!--available-->
      <th>Sold</th>
      <!--used-->
      <th>Result</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>30</td>
    <!--available-->
    <td>4</td>
    <!--used-->
    <td><span class="result"></span></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>20 <br/> 20</td>
    <!--available-->
    <td>6 <br/> 5</td>
    <!--used-->
    <td><span class="result"></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$('tr').each(function() {
    var value1 = parseInt($(this).find("td:eq(0)").text(), 10);
    var value2 = parseInt($(this).find("td:eq(1)").text(), 10);
    var result = $(this).find(".result")
    var valueFinal = (value2*100)/value1
    $(result).html(valueFinal)
    
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Avalable</th> <!--available-->
<th>Sold</th> <!--used-->
<th>Result</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tr>
<td>30</td> <!--available-->
<td>4</td> <!--used-->
<td><span class="result"></span></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>20 <br/> 20</td> <!--available-->
<td>6  <br/> 5</td>  <!--used-->
<td><span class="result"></span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here yo go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/kr6mtq21/

```js
$('tr').each(function(){
  $(this).find('span.result').html(((parseInt($(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').text()) * 100) / parseInt($(this).find('td:nth-child(1)').text())).toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Avalable</th> <!--available-->
      <th>Sold</th> <!--used-->
      <th>Result</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>30</td> <!--available-->
    <td>4</td> <!--used-->
    <td><span class="result"></span></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>20 </td> <!--available-->
    <td>6  </td>  <!--used-->
    <td><span class="result"></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have following table ( set id for your table, maybe there will be some table on your page and that will ruin your tables)

```js
    (function($){   
     $('document').ready(function(){ 
    $('#mytable tr').each(function(index) {
       // skip first row
       if(index !=0 ){
        var value1 = parseInt($(this).find("td:eq(0)").text(), 10);
        var value2 = parseInt($(this).find("td:eq(1)").text(), 10);
        var result = $(this).find(".result");
        var valueFinal = (value2/value1)*100;
        $(result).html(valueFinal + "% Sold");
       }
      })
    });
    }
    )(jQuery);
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table border="1" id="mytable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Avalable</th> <!--available-->
    <th>Sold</th> <!--used-->
    <th>Result</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
    <td>10</td> <!--available-->
    <td>5</td> <!--used-->
    <td><span class="result"></span></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td>20</td> <!--available-->
    <td>12</td>  <!--used-->
    <td><span class="result"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>40</td> <!--available-->
    <td>6</td>  <!--used-->
    <td><span class="result"></span></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: @aynaz where did you put jquery code?  have you added it to page inline or do you put it in an external js file and have you added it to the page?

Comment: @aynaz I update my code and have been providing the snippet for you.

Comment: i added it to page inline

Comment: thank you but this is not what i want. not a number for two of them

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```js
$('.result').each((i, e) => {
  var $e = $(e);
  var r = $e.parent().parent().find('td');
  var p;
  if(/\<br\>/.test(r[0].innerHTML)) {
    var a_arr = r[0].innerHTML.split('<br>');
    var s_arr = r[1].innerHTML.split('<br>');
    a_arr.forEach((e,i) => {
      var t = parseInt((s_arr[i]/e)*100) + " <br>";
      p = p ? p + t : t;
    });
  } else {
    p = parseInt((r[1].innerHTML/r[0].innerHTML) * 100);
  }
  console.log(p);
  $e.html(p)
  console.log();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table border="1">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Avalable</th> <!--available-->
    <th>Sold</th> <!--used-->
    <th>Result</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
    <td>30</td> <!--available-->
    <td>4</td> <!--used-->
    <td><span class="result"></span></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>20 <br/> 20</td> <!--available-->
    <td>6  <br/> 5</td>  <!--used-->
    <td><span class="result"></span></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```